# How to grab the value of a radio button with Liquid?

Tags: liquid

I'm trying to set a background color based on what text color the user sets in Shopify admin. How can I grab the value of the radio button and set the background color accordingly? I'd prefer to use Liquid, if possible.

Here is my JSON format to display 2 radio buttons in admin:

```
  {
     "type":      "radio",
     "id":        "color_banner_text",
     "label":     "Text Color",
     "options": [
       { "value": "#ffffff", "label": "Light" },
       { "value": "#666666", "label": "Dark" }
     ],
     "default":   "#666666"
  }
```

And this is what I've tried so far:

```
<div class="{% if block.settings.color_banner_text == "#ffffff" % } background-dark {% else %} background-light {% endif %}">
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks good, what's your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why do not do like this

```
<div style="background-color: {{block.settings.color_banner_text}};"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here we cannot see if it's within a block element or just in the schema. If it's not in a block element, you could try to replace

```
block.settings.color_banner_text
```

with

```
section.settings.color_banner_text
```

Also, check your classes "background-dark" and "background-light" this is from where the color should came from. And not from the radio values.